Syncfusion Angular Grid Does not update when when the data changes
I have a Syncfusion GridComponent in an angular application.
I have datasource bound to an angular signal:
  <ejs-grid
    grid
    [allowRowDragAndDrop]="allowDragAndDrop"
    [sortSettings]="sortOptions"
    (rowDrop)="rowDrop($event)"
    [dataSource]="plans()"
    (rowSelected)='rowSelected($event)'
    [toolbar]="toolbar"
    [loadingIndicator]="loadingIndicator"
    (toolbarClick)="clickHandler($event)"
  >

  </ejs-grid>

The signal is updated via subscription:
   this.service.get(id)
    .pipe(
      take(1),
      tap((plans: Plan[]) => {
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.plans.set(plans);
      }),
    )

The network call is being made, the data is being returned and the signal is updated.  The grid however does not update until another action is selected.
I have tried changing out the datasource to an observable with an async pipe, i.e:
plans$ | async

Again the data is updated - but the grid is not.
